# How to update Twisters output instead of creating new one

Tags: javascript

I have a list of addresses and I use a function to get the balance of each address and display it in the terminal using the Twisters package.

The problem is that every time the function is executed, a new text is printed in the terminal.

I want to edit the first printed text and display the new information without printing a new text.

```
const twisters = new Twisters();
let ethExecuted = 1;
const ethEvmosAddress = [
    "0x517daba2695244ace417758f72d0dfb8efa0ad59",
    "0xb1911d8ffcc2d8ca6c5ea4f4f18be6ea675c1ce7",
];

function getRandomAddress() {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ethEvmosAddress.length);
  
    return ethEvmosAddress[index];
}

export const getEthWalletBalance = () => {
    const address = getRandomAddress();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        checkEthBalance(address)
            .then((balance) => {
                twisters.put(address, {
                    text: `
                        == Ethereum account balance Information ==
                        Account : ${address}
                        ETH Balance : ${balance}
                        Executed : ${ethExecuted}
                        `,
                    replace: true
                });
                resolve();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error occurred:", error);
                reject(error);
            });
    });
};



const handleInterrupt = () => {
    console.log("User interrupted. Exiting...");
    process.exit(0);
  };
  process.on("SIGINT", handleInterrupt);
  
  (async () => {
    try {
      while (true) {
        try {
            await getEthWalletBalance();
            ethExecuted += 1;
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5 * 1000));
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error occurred ", error);
        }
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, interval * 1000));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Unexpected error occurred ", error);
    } finally {
      process.removeListener("SIGINT", handleInterrupt);
    }
  })();
```